# Main Type Error

Tags: java, types, program-entry-point

I have been working on my game for some time but I have just noticed that there is a bin folder that has the same exact file system as in my main package. I deleted it and now it says no main class found com.thecherno.rain.game      My main class is game though.
I also can't figure out how to put the code on here so if you need it you will need to tell me how to.

Comment: When you want to use a tool, you should learn how to use it. Don't just delete stuff. And read a FAQ on how to post.

Comment: You need to recompile. The bin folder holds all your .class files. You can't run a program with .java files, only by .class files.

Comment: maybe you have deleted your compiled classes, try to compile your source code again.

Answer (score 2):

```
ProjectRoot
          bin
             com
                thechurno
                        rain
                           game
                               Main.class  // program runs from this .class file
                                           // when you delete it, your program wont run
          src
             com
                thechurno
                        rain
                           game
                               Main.java  // java source code won't run program
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly execute a .java file. You need to first compile it, which creates a highly optimized .class file. It is this file that is actually executed when you run the program.

Read more on java and class files

[how to use a .class file with .java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510564/how-to-use-a-class-file-with-java-files)

[how to convert .java file to a .class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296249/how-to-convert-java-file-to-a-class-file)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html